# Putting images onto an excel sheet via URL links

Tags: vba, excel, macros

My sheet has three columns, "A" = Images, "B" = Image Names, and "C" = URL Links, with Rows 1 and 2 being used as headers and rows 3 to 1002 for user input. The Current working code will search for the image names in Column "B" in the folder you select, and inserts them into Column "A". This macro runs off of a commandbutton I have placed on a userform I have created.

Working code is as follows (this is a edited version of the accepted answer [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/92490/finding-and-pasting-images-into-a-specific-cell)):

```
Private Sub Add_Images_Click()
Const EXIT_TEXT         As String = ""
Const NO_PICTURE_FOUND  As String = "No picture found"

Dim picName             As String
Dim picFullName         As String
Dim rowIndex            As Long
Dim lastRow             As Long
Dim selectedFolder      As String
Dim data()              As Variant
Dim wks                 As Worksheet
Dim Cell                As Range
Dim pic                 As Picture

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

selectedFolder = GetFolder
If Len(selectedFolder) = 0 Then GoTo ExitRoutine

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set wks = ActiveSheet
lastRow = wks.Cells(2, "B").End(xlDown).Row
data = wks.Range(wks.Cells(3, "B"), wks.Cells(lastRow, "B")).Value2

For rowIndex = 3 To UBound(data, 1)
    If StrComp(data(rowIndex, 1), EXIT_TEXT, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then GoTo ExitRoutine

    picName = data(rowIndex, 1)
    picFullName = selectedFolder & picName

    If Len(Dir(picFullName)) > 0 Then
        Set Cell = wks.Cells(rowIndex, "A")
        Set pic = wks.Pictures.Insert(picFullName)
        With pic
            .ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
            .Height = Cell.Height
            .Width = Cell.Width
            .Top = Cell.Top
            .Left = Cell.Left
            .Placement = xlMoveAndSize
        End With
    Else
        wks.Cells(rowIndex, "A").Value = NO_PICTURE_FOUND
    End If
Next rowIndex

ExitRoutine:
Set wks = Nothing
Set pic = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
UserForm.Hide
Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
MsgBox Prompt:="Unable to find photo", _
       Title:="An error occured", _
       Buttons:=vbExclamation
Resume ExitRoutine

End Sub
Private Function GetFolder() As String
Dim selectedFolder  As String
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .InitialFileName = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\"
    .Title = "Select the folder containing the Image/PDF files."
    .Show

    If .SelectedItems.count > 0 Then
        selectedFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
        If Right$(selectedFolder, 1) <> Application.PathSeparator Then _
            selectedFolder = selectedFolder & Application.PathSeparator
    End If
End With
GetFolder = selectedFolder
End Function
```

I'm looking for a way to edit this macro so that it would be able to use the URL links for the images in Column "C" and find and insert the images into Column "A" that way. I found a working code (can't remember where, or I'd link it) that I tried to adapt with my current code to achieve the desired results.

The sample code I found online:

```
Sub Images_Via_URL()
Dim url_column As Range
Dim image_column As Range

Set url_column = Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Columns("A")
Set image_column = Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Columns("B")

Dim i As Long
For i = 2 To url_column.Cells.Count

  With image_column.Worksheet.Pictures.Insert(url_column.Cells(i).Value)
    .Left = image_column.Cells(i).Left
    .Top = image_column.Cells(i).Top
    .Height = 100
    .Width = 100
  End With
Next
End Sub
```

The following code is my failed attempt to edit it myself. It worked once for a list of 7 URL links, then I deleted one of the links in the middle to see if it would handle the blank cell correctly, and now it flat out wont work. It goes into the "ExitRoutine" every time.

Not Working Code:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub URL_Images_Click()

Const EXIT_TEXT         As String = ""
Const NO_PICTURE_FOUND  As String = "No picture found"

Dim picURL              As String
Dim rowIndex            As Long
Dim lastRow             As Long
Dim data()              As Variant
Dim wks                 As Worksheet
Dim Cell                As Range
Dim pic                 As Picture

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set wks = ActiveSheet
lastRow = wks.Cells(2, "B").End(xlDown).Row
data = wks.Range(wks.Cells(3, "C"), wks.Cells(lastRow, "C")).Value2

For rowIndex = 3 To UBound(data, 1)
    **If StrComp(data(rowIndex, 1), EXIT_TEXT, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then GoTo ExitRoutine**

    picURL = data(rowIndex, 1)

    If Len(picURL) > 0 Then
        Set Cell = wks.Cells(rowIndex, "A")
        Set pic = wks.Pictures.Insert(picURL)
        With pic
            .ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
            .Height = Cell.Height
            .Width = Cell.Width
            .Top = Cell.Top
            .Left = Cell.Left
            .Placement = xlMoveAndSize
        End With
    Else
        wks.Cells(rowIndex, "A").Value = NO_PICTURE_FOUND
    End If

Next rowIndex

ExitRoutine:
Set wks = Nothing
Set pic = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
UserForm.Hide
Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
MsgBox Prompt:="Unable to find photo", _
       Title:="An error occured", _
       Buttons:=vbExclamation
Resume ExitRoutine

End Sub
```

I've bolded the line that is forcing it to the "ExitRoutine". I'm not sure how exactly that line works as I am not the one who originally wrote it. Any help would be great!

Comment: What's the value of `lastRow` when it fails?  A simpler test would be `If Len(data(rowIndex, 1)) = 0 Then GoTo ExitRoutine`

Answer (score 0):

```
lastRow = wks.Cells(2, "B").End(xlDown).Row
data = wks.Range(wks.Cells(3, "C"), wks.Cells(lastRow, "C")).Value2

For rowIndex = 3 To UBound(data, 1)
    '....
```

If you start at rowIndex = 3 then you're skipping the first two rows of your input data: a 2-D array from a range always has lower bounds of 1 for both dimensions, regardless of the location of the range.

In this case `data(1,1)` will correspond to C3, whereas `data(3,1)` is C5